# How should I access a function of a container class in a contained class object

Tags: c++, callback

I have the following class structure

```
class containingClass
{

    int func1(int a);
    containedClass containedClassObject;
}
```

I want to access `func1` in `containedClass` objects. What will be the best way to achieve that?

A naive solution that comes to mind is to pass a function pointer to the `containedClass`'s constructor, but then I get into a circular definition, as I need to pass a pointer to an object of the `containingClass` as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You will always need `containingClass` and an instance of it to be calling a member function in that class. That's the bad news. The good news is that you can do it indirectly using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: i think the real question here should be "is there another, more logical way to express the relationship between the services offered by `containingClass` and `containedClass` "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `containedClass` required a contract/API/function to be fulfilled by the `int func1(int)` member of the `containingClass`. Unless the `containedClass` explicitly requires access to an instance of the `containingClass` for other purposes, the access can be provided via lambda (or `std::bind`) and the `containedClass` can have a `std::function` with the correct signature member that holds the lambda.

The only "trick" here would be to ensure that the lifetime of the objects are managed appropriately, i.e. the lifetime of the `containingClass` instance is at least as long as required for use in the `containedClassObject` object.

A sample;

```
#include <functional>
class containedClass {
    std::function<int(int)> functor_;
public:
    void setter(std::function<int(int)> functor) { functor_ = functor; }
};

class containingClass
{
    int func1(int a);
    containedClass containedClassObject;

public:
    containingClass()
    {
        containedClassObject.setter([this](int a) -> int { return this->func1(a); });
    }
};
```

Comment: This solution makes sense. I also figured another solution (at least theoretically). I can make my `containingClass` implement an interface which has `func1` as the only pure virtual function. I will pass the `this pointer` of the `containingClass` to `containedClass` where the `containedClass`  expects a pointer to just the interface and hence can access just func1 through this system. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @TheBlueNotebook. That sounds like it should work as well. The exact details of one over the other would depend a lot on the abstraction in the code. Both would work - chose the the one that makes the most sense in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this already over a year old, I would like to help other seraching people.

Here is another example using a reference to the containing class. Tested with mingw32-g++ 4.9.2 and -std=c++98. Means it should work also with c++0x and c++11

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class clsDog;

class clsEar{
    public:
    clsDog& myDog;
    clsEar(clsDog &dog);
};

class clsDog{
    public:
    clsEar ear;
    void pain(string fromPart){
        cout << "dog has pain in his " << fromPart << endl;
    }
    clsDog():ear(*this){};
};

clsEar::clsEar(clsDog &dog): myDog(dog){
    myDog.pain("ear");
}

int main(){
    clsDog dog;
}
```

First `class clsDog` makes it available for reference and pointers. **NOT** for actual values like non reference member variables.

In `class clsEar` a reference to `clsDog` is created using `clsDog& myDog`. The constructor can set the reference pointer in the initializer list. It is important that the containing class `clsDog` is passed by reference otherwise the compiler tell you that the class incomplete.

Because `clsEar` is now fully defined a normal member variable of `clsEar` can be defined in `clsDog`. Because `clsEar`'s constructor needs a reference to `clsDog` it must be passed to it's constructor. This is done in the initialisier list of `clsDog`'s constructor by passing `*this`.

Last but not least the implementation of `clsEar::clsEar` must be done. It is necessary to do this after the complete definition of `clsDog` to call the member functions or access member varibales of `clsDog` in `clsEar`. Otherwise the compiler will tell you again, that the class `clsDog` is of incomplete type.